# Is this sentence correct grammatically? (using article)

Tags: grammaticality, articles

We need to use this method to explore any a new idea? or

We need to use this method to explore any new idea?

Answer (score 3):

Both **a** and **any** are determiners and you don't need to use them both, so, either one is sufficient. Consequently, the correct sentence would be either:

> We need to use this method to explore any new idea.

or

> We need to use this method to explore a new idea.